# SpecialCharacters in aspx URL

Tags: typescript, sharepoint

I have a URL like this:

```
xyz.com/sites/germany/Pages/März_2017_P.aspx
```

Now when I am doing like this in Typescript:

```
var sPath = window.location.pathname;
```

I am getting this:

```
/sites/germany/Pages/M%C3%A4rz_2017_P.aspx
```

But I want this special character name in the same format. Can someone please suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [decodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) method to parse the url special characters:

```
let url = '/sites/germany/Pages/M%C3%A4rz_2017_P.aspx';
console.log(url);
let decode = decodeURI(url);
console.log(decode);
```

Logs:

/sites/germany/Pages/M%C3%A4rz_2017_P.aspx

/sites/germany/Pages/März_2017_P.aspx